# C-o instead of C-c Prefix key

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

I'm new to emacs and I'd like to replace the full functionality of `C-c` with `C-o`, while freeing up `C-c` for other uses.
I tried to do this, but I get an error when calling `C-o`.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-o") 'mode-specific-map)
```

error message is :

```
wrong type argument: commandp, mode-specific-map
```

Also, I would like to understand if this line of thinking is feasible? I would like to replace `C-c` completely with `C-o` and then use `C-c` to bind the yank function, is it possible to ensure that something like org mode, which uses a lot of `C-c`, will still work?

I've learned about CUA mode, but I don't feel comfortable with CUA mode's copy-region, that's why I'm trying to bind `C-c` to a normal yank, but it seems I can't safely release it either.

Comment: This seems very ill-advised. C-c is a general prefix for mode-speciific bindings; you are in for a world of trouble if you try to repurpose a reserved key, even if you managed to solve the technical hurdles.

Comment: Like the error message tells you, `global-set-key` expects a command as its second argument. The lower-level `define-key` would let you remap prefix keybindings etc.